# Use {{yield}} inside {{each}} in Ember.Component

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to use `{{yield}}` inside a  `{{each}}` helper in a Ember.Component?

So I can provide a repating structure with a component, and maybe a add/remove line functionality, but I can provive handlebars markup from outside and use the `{{yield}}` helper to access that.

Thats what I wanna do:

items:

```
[{
    name: 'stack',
    value: 5
}, {
    name: 'overflow',
    value: 8
}]
```

template:

```
{{#show-list value=items}}
    {{name}} - {{value}}
{{/show-list}}
```

component:

```
<ul>
    {{#each value}}
        <li>{{yield}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And thats what I expect back:

```
<ul>
    <li>stack - 5</li>
    <li>overflow - 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the only way to do this is [overriding the _yield method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20109930/1846480), I personally don't like this because the `_yield` seems private, but it's the only way I know. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in Ember using public APIs.

See this twitter post from Yehuda: 
https://twitter.com/wycats/status/536723973745410048

And this demo:
http://jsbin.com/yawasisofu/4/edit?html,js,output

In your case, the component should look like:

```
<ul>
  {{#each value as listItem}}
    <li>{{yield listItem}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```